# How Do I Enable ADB Debugging on Chrome OS?

Tags: android, androidappsonchromeos

According to both [Google](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/9770692) and [Google](https://developer.android.com/topic/arc/development-environment?hl=en#enable_adb_debug), if I enable Linux on Chrome OS, then in Settings' "Linux (Beta)" section, I should see a "Develop Android apps" option.

- On an HP Chromebox G2 (Kench), I see this option and eventually got it activated.
- On a Samsung Chromebook Plus (Kevin), I do not see this option, even with Chrome OS 88.0.4324.186.
- On an ASUS Chromebook Tablet CT100 (scarlet), I see this option. This particular device is short on ports, though, so I'm going to be struggling to use it for what I need.
- On an Acer Chromebook R11 (cyan), I do not see this option, even with Chrome OS 88.0.4324.186.

So... how do I enable ADB debugging on the Samsung or the Acer?

Or, another way to look at it: how do I know whether a given Chrome OS device model will or will not support ADB debugging, besides actually trying to set it up? It is difficult to plan on getting something else for testing if I do not know whether it will support ADB before buying it.

Comment: You may want to list the codename of the Chrome OS device, either from: https://cros-updates-serving.appspot.com/ or https://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/developer-information-for-chrome-os-devices

Comment: Based on your first link, I think it is a `caroline`. Is there a good way to get this info from the device itself? I *think* it's a Chromebook Pro, but it's been a while, and I couldn't figure out where in Chrome OS's Settings it shows the make/model of the Chromebook.

Comment: I believe its either in Help->About ChromeOS -> Detailed Build Information or chrome://system page. Checking this on a older Chromebook, the codename appears to be part of firmware tag or on the system page the codename is part of the release-board name. Chromebook Recovery tool also lists codename/model number of device.

Comment: OK, I have now tried four Chrome OS devices, with varying results. I was wrong on the Samsung model (Chromebook Plus, not Chromebook Pro), and I have the codenames listed.

Comment: And just to make sure, you've done a powerwash/reset (in case you were playing with system flags) on all of these devices?

Comment: I did a powerwash/reset on the Acer. I did not on the Samsung, as it was never in developer mode and so I had no particular need to do so.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/g/crouton-central/c/wmW7haQe2PE

Comment: @UsamaAltaf: Thanks, but all of that is out of date AFAICT.

Comment: Did you make sure your samsung is not in developer mode?

Comment: @ALUFTW: It never was in developer mode. I specifically left it out of developer mode to have a Chrome OS device that was normal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It's a known issue since September 20.**

There is no official response from google about this issue yet.

According to Google's product platinum expert [DennyL](https://support.google.com/chromebook/profile/6602):

> "I believe it has to do with the architecture and/or the kernel version used on the device" .........  "So far, **there have been no authoritative responses** but we hope to see something soon."

Source: https://support.google.com/chromebook/thread/71852070?hl=en

Answer (score 5):

With Linux development environment (Beta) enabled,

Go to Settings of the Chromebook 
Enter "android" on the search bar on top, 
Select "manage Android preferences" 
then you will enter generic Android setting  page in a new window.

Scroll down at bottom select "System", 
then select "Developer options"

I found my ADB debugging there.

Answer (score 2):

looks like that devices without TPM 2.0 will never get this feature.
this following issue was marked as won't fix

Source: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1072174